# How to properly rotate image and labels for semantic segmentation data augmentation in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, data-augmentation, image-preprocessing

What's a proper procedure for doing the image and label rotation for semantic segmentation in dataset augmentation using Tensorflow?

### Images

I have seen the function [tf.contib.image.rotate()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/rotate), but this function fills empty space with zeros (from docs):

> Empty space due to the rotation will be filled with zeros.

I would like to fill that empty space with a different value (maybe some constant, like the dataset mean pixel). How this can be done in Tensorflow (I know that there are options in [Keras Image Preprocessing](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), but I need TF)?

### Labels

Also, what about the labels? If I just use the same function (`tf.contrib.image.rotate()`), it will fill the empty space with zeros suggesting that pixel in those places belong to class with id 0 (since I have class labeled with 0). The one solution could be to put ignore label on those pixels (e.g. 255), but, again, the current function doesn't support default fill value ...

Comment: Use different Augmenter Library; there are quite a few which are good enough.. Augmentor etc

Comment: But Augmentor cannot integrate with Tensorflow graph? I see in their docs that it integrates with Keras, but I need Tensorflow graph integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following solution.

### Labels

Here is a snippet filling an empty space in label with ignore label.

```
IGNORE_LABEL = 255
label = tf.subtract(label, IGNORE_LABEL)
label = tf.contib.image.rotate(label, angle)
label = tf.add(label, IGNORE_LABEL)
```

This way, by subtracting `IGNORE_LABEL`, you shift the interval to [-255, 0]. When `label` (segmentation labels) is rotated, empty spaces are filled with zeros. By adding back `IGNORE_LABEL`, you shift interval back to [0, 255] meaning that empty space is set to `IGNORE_LABEL`.

### Images

Similar trick can be applied to image rotation to fill empty space with preferred value.